# In Bazel, is it possible to use a function output as input to a load statement?

Tags: bazel

In Bazel, is it possible to use simple functions and variables as input to a load statement?

For example:

```py
my_workspace = "a" + "b"

load(my_workspace, "foo")
load(my_workspace, "bar")
```

> WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
>
> ERROR: error loading package 'loadtest/simple': malformed load statements

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe there's another way to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: @Erran The workspace names are generated by a tool, so they are computed using a function.

Comment: I don't think you have any control over the loading phase besides using BUILD and WORKSPACE files.
Maybe you could try to create a [repository rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html) which would compute which workspace to load, load it, and then bind it to a constant name. That constant name is the one you would reference in your BUILD file.
The workspace which wants to load the other workspace can be created with a repository_rule

Comment: @Erran Do you mean I could programatically create an "alias" (local to a workspace) from `"friendly_name"` to `"programatic_name_e811a524994"`? Then consumers could write `load("friendly_name", "foo")` which would be interpreted by Bazel as `load("programatic_name_e811a524994", "foo")`

Comment: No not exactly. In short, a `repository_rule`, when instantiated, generates a workspace.
In this case, when generating said workspace, the rule would generate a `WORKSPACE` file which contains `local_repository` rules. The `name` of each `local_repository` is `friendly_name` and the `path` would be the `programatic_name_e811a524994`.
I still don't understand what the source of the names of the workspaces you want.

Comment: And forget what I said about "binding" the [bind](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#bind) function is for targets (and also not recommended to be used)

Comment: @Erran I will leave this question as-is, since it is well defined and has a good answer. Motivation for this question is this issue, which might interest you! https://github.com/LoopPerfect/buckaroo/issues/371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact error message might have changed with version, I'd see:

> `syntax error at 'my_workspace': expected string literal`

but no, you cannot use anything but string literal as per [docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#load):

> Use the `load` statement to import a symbol from an extension.
>
> ...
>
> Arguments must be string literals (no variable)...